# Merging files on the basis of common data

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two csv files

File 1 :

```
799001,8_802,3122,627654
```

File 2 :

```
799001,567765,v567575
```

When i try to merge the two files with column 1 as the key, I can see that the files are getting merged, however column 3 of file1 is not getting printed.

My output :

```
799001,2_802_3122,567765,v567575
```

Expected output :

```
799001,2_802_3122,627654,567765,v567575
```

I tried this :

```
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } FNR == NR { names[$1] = $2; next } ($1 in names) { print $1, names[$1], $2 , $3 , $4 }' file1 file2
```

Why is column3 not getting merged ?

Comment: You seem to expect `file2` to have four columns. I expect this is a typo and you simply meant to feed `file2` in to your `awk` code before `file1`.

Comment: I actually want my file two to be placed after the file1

Comment: What happen if you swap the two on the command line? Also, where does `2_802_3122` come from?

Comment: When i try this 
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } FNR == NR { names[$1] = $2; next } ($1 in names) { print $1, names[$1], $2 }' file1 file2. It skips the 3rd column of file1 and 3rd column of file2.. so I tried adding $3 and $4

Comment: If i swap the two files, column 3 of file2 gets skipped and rest of the columns are printed.

Comment: please double check your file1 and file2 and compare what you shown us as your expected output which doesn't seems completely relevant to your inputs and so [edit] and make it clear how it returned to that output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two files are sorted on the join field (the first comma-delimited field), then you may use

```
$ join -t , file1 file2
799001,8_802,3122,627654,567765,v567575
```

If the data is not sorted, you need to pre-sort it, either by creating new sorted files, or using a process substitution (in shells that support these):

```
$ join -t , <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
799001,8_802,3122,627654,567765,v567575
```

If you don't *want* to sort the data, because you want to preserve the order of one or the other file, then you may use `awk` like so:

```
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == FNR { key[$1] = $0; next } ($1 in key) { k = $1; sub("^[^,]*,",""); print key[k], $0 }' file1 file2
799001,8_802,3122,627654,567765,v567575
```

This is *similar* to what you have, but saves *the whole line* in the associative array.  The `print` statement then outputs the saved value from the first file along thing the line from the second file, apart from the first field which is removed using `sub()`.

The variable `k` in the second part of the code is needed as the call to `sub()` changes the value of `$1`.

The call to `sub()` assumes that `FS` is a comma.  To instead use the actual value of `FS`, no matter what it is, use

```c
sub("^[^" FS "]*" FS,"")
```

instead.  This would work provided `FS` is a single character.

Would you want to use your prior knowledge of the number of fields in the second file, you may avoid the somewhat messy call to `sub()` and the `k` variable with

```
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == FNR { key[$1] = $0; next } ($1 in key) { print key[$1], $2, $3 }' file1 file2
799001,8_802,3122,627654,567765,v567575
```